# How to only output branch versions and do not really start the build

Tags: yocto

When run:

```
green@green13:~/green/build$bitbake core-image-minimal
```

I can see the branch versions as below and it will start the build but I only need these info outputs and do not really need to start the build, how can I do it?

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemuarm64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.14"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 armv8a crc"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "HEAD:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
meta-oe              
meta-python          
meta-filesystems     
meta-networking      = "HEAD:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
meta-virtualization  = "HEAD:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
bitbake core-image-minimal -n
```

*-n* arguments performs a dry run, technically it starts the build but it wont do much and it'll finish in a few seconds.

For example:

```
$ bitbake core-image-minimal -n
Loading cache: 100% |#############################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1522 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.53.1"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux-musl"
MACHINE              = "qemuarm64"
DISTRO               = "poky-tiny"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.4+snapshot-37b9d6ee2faa5aacb5324d083ba4a7ba8560b5cd"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 armv8a crc cortexa57"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "master-next:37b9d6ee2faa5aacb5324d083ba4a7ba8560b5cd"
Initialising tasks: 100% |########################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Sstate summary: Wanted 559 Local 0 Mirrors 0 Missed 559 Current 151 (0% match, 21% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2036 tasks of which 634 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
```

See usage and syntax in the [bitbake manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/singleindex.html#usage-and-syntax) for more info.